# Solution of a differential equation in physics

Tags: oscillators, complex-numbers, dissipation, linear-systems

In physics when we solve the differential equation, in some cases we get two part of  the solution, one is real and another is imaginary. Some cases we consider that the real part have some physical significance and the imaginary apart signifies the oscillating term or the absorption term. Why we consider this and the imaginary part says about the absorption or oscillation?

Comment: Can you provide an example? So any answer can be more concrete

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oftentimes in physics, we study phenomena that oscillate with a certain frequency, which we'll call $\omega$. These phenomena are usually modeled as the real part of a complex function $e^{i\omega t}$. These oscillations have a tendency to decay exponentially in response to damping, and so are more accurately modeled as $e^{-\beta t}e^{i\omega t}$ for some decay rate $\beta$.

This damped oscillation is most conveniently written as a single exponential function, which is rather obvious when you write

$$e^{-\beta t}e^{i\omega t}=e^{-\beta t+i\omega t}=e^{i(\omega+i\beta)t}=e^{i\eta t}$$

where $\eta=\omega+i\beta$ is a **complex** frequency where the real part is the oscillation rate and the imaginary part is the decay rate.

Comment: great summary. this is why I read the answers here.